# WPF DataGridHeaderTemplate as a button

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, prism

I'm trying to get my DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header to be a button and run  a command once clicked.  Using DelegateCommand in the ViewModel to delete entities that is checked.

```
        <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Image Source="../Images/SearchIcon.jpg" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

       </DataGrid>
```

Does anyone know why this doesnt work?  I also disabled the column sorting when you click the header, hoping it would run my button.
Maybe the header is a container where my button is hidden in the back?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="ProxyKey" Value="{Binding}"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
...
<Button Command="{Binding Value.DeleteCommand, Source={StaticResource ProxyKey}}">
```

See if this solves your problem.